# SKLL and Kappa for Non-numeric Values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am attempting to calculate Cohen's kappa for non-numeric values with the scikit learn library. Is there a way to convert an array of labels ["happy","sad","happy"] to a floats?

```
from skll.metrics import kappa
y_true = ["HAPPINESS","OTHER","NONE","FEAR","NONE","NONE","NONE","ANGER"]
y_pred = ["HAPPINESS","NONE","NONE","FEAR","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"] 
kappa_val = kappa(y_true, y_pred)
```

Right now I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "HAPPINESS"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `LabelEncoder`

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import classification
import numpy as np
y_true = ["HAPPINESS","OTHER","NONE","FEAR","NONE","NONE","NONE","ANGER"]
y_pred = ["HAPPINESS","NONE","NONE","FEAR","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"] 
enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
enc.fit(np.hstack((y_pred, y_true))) #have to give it all possible labels
kappa_val = classification.cohen_kappa_score(enc.transform(y_true), enc.transform(y_pred))
print kappa_val
```

Which gives the output

```
0.578947368421
```